# Why does std::strlen() work on char arrays WITHOUT terminating null characters? Is this a compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, c-strings, strlen, array-initialization

All of the reading I've done says that passing a non null-terminated char array to `std::strlen` is undefined behavior and will likely cause the program to crash. However, the code below (compiled with g++ on Cygwin) works just fine.

What is going on here?

```
char test_cases[4][80] = {{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'}, {}, {'1'}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}};
size_t num_test_cases = std::size(test_cases); // C++17

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_test_cases; ++i) 
{
    std::cout << std::strlen(test_cases[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
13
0
1
3
```

Comment: What do you think you have after your strings?

Comment: Sooner or later a zero-value character will probably be encountered. But you are in undefined behaviour land - it just seems to "work".

Comment: Your array initializers are shorter than 80 chars, so the remaining characters are filled with `'\0'`.

Comment: Isn't it perfectly defined? They are zero initialized, which is `0` for char.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Actually they are value initialized, which leads to the zero initialization.  Default initialization would leave it with an indeterminate value.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, yes, that was what I meant, I was looking up where `int a[10] = {};` lead to zero intiialized values.

Comment: To explain the downvotes (which I don't necessarily agree with): Asking "why does my code that should have undefined behavior work as normal?" is usually not very productive because undefined behavior _includes_ the possibility of "everything works". Now, if you tried _really hard_ to get Bad Things to happen and still can't make them happen, that may be indeed grounds for a question. But otherwise, don't assume that everything that can go wrong will go wrong (no matter what a certain Mr Murphy may tell you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of arrays means any unused slots are conveniently set to zero size.

So what you wrote is entirely legal and consistent.

Had you defined your buffer size exactly right for "Hello, world!"

```
char test_cases[4][13]
```

You would have got the "broken" answer, and touched the edge of UB.

Also because you declared that as the first buffer, it will run on into the second buffer, so will give a wrong answer rather than some fatal error.

Actually, looking again, because you defined the second string as empty, you STILL wouldn't see an error, as the first byte of the overflowing data is perhaps also zero-filled!

I say perhaps, because {} with no value is actually NOT legal C. It is legal C++11, but I'm not entirely sure if the behaviour is to ensure all members are zeroed if the C++11 aggregate "style" initialisers are invoked. In fact, because of your output, {} must have done the "right" thing.

Usually there are so many zeros in memory that your strings will usually be terminated eventually! As @John mentioned, this is an opportunity for aliens to steal money from your bank account.

Comment: *Also because you declared that as the first buffer, it will run on into the second buffer, so will give a wrong answer rather than some fatal error.* while this will normally be what happens formally it is UB and you cannot depend on that behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver worse, because it's UB, a smart compiler will replace your entire codebase with a no-op. Or a trojan that steals your bank credentials and donates your money to the compiler author. Or NetHack.

Comment: "Conveniently", but not by chance, it's perfectly defined.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Very funny. Although it is defined in modern compilers as "undefined" - at least in C++, the layout of a 2-dimensional array has been "well known" for over 50 years. Doesn't make it right, but does mean I can rely on it.

Comment: @GemTaylor The predictability of the layout isn't really the point. There is more to life than layouts.

Comment: @JohnDvorak That's assuming all path provably leads to UB. It's possible to have a program with UB on some branches that behaves correctly if the user input is such that those branches are never taken.

Answer (score 3):

Your case is a usual case of "zero initialization". [It's perfectly defined.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)

> **Initialization from brace-enclosed lists**
>
> When an array is initialized with a brace-enclosed list of initializers, the first initializer in the list initializes the array element at index zero (unless a designator is specified) (since C99), and each subsequent initializer without a designator (since C99)initializes the array element at index one greater than the one initialized by the previous initializer.

As you have more than 13 characters allocated (80), all the others are filled with `'\0'` (the character with a value of `0`). So `strlen` works exactly as expected because you have more room than what you expect.

Additional examples from cppreference that are EXACTLY your case:

```
int x[] = {1,2,3}; // x has type int[3] and holds 1,2,3
int y[5] = {1,2,3}; // y has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
int z[3] = {0}; // z has type int[3] and holds all zeroes
```

Comment: I see, so when extra space in an array is filled with zeroes, are these actually null characters?

Comment: @brianxk93 The `char` with value `0` is literally a null character. That's what that means. (To the extent that the phrase "null character" has meaning, anyway)

Comment: I'm a little confused by that - I thought the char with value '\0' (escaped zero) is the null character.. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The null character `'\0'` is a representation of the ASCII character that has a value of `0`. Otherwise, we would not be able to put such a character in a string.

Comment: I think I understand: The "null character" is 0, not '0', and is represented in code with '\0'. Simply typing '0' is representing the number zero as a character, as I would when creating numerical strings like "100". Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly. the "number" 0 has not a value of 0 when represented as a character.

Comment: @brianxk93 `'\0'` means a `char` literal with the numeric value 0. You can put other values if you want. Try `'\5'` for the `char` with the numeric value 5. You just never see that because it's never useful.

Answer (score 2):

> says that passing a non null-terminated char array to std::strlen is undefined behavior

Correct.

> However, the code below works just fine.

All of the strings *are* null terminated and thus no undefined behaviour.

Regardless, you cannot assume that a program having undefined behaviour wouldn't appear to "work just fine". There is nothing unconventional about that.

> and will likely cause the program to crash.

It is not a good idea to expect undefined behaviour to "likely cause the program to crash". It is entirely possible for UB to not cause the program to crash.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I agree with the last part as well - a program with undefined behavior that continues to work is scary indeed!